# select * from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building php search box and this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.title AND table2.posts LIKE '$query%' LIMIT 10
```

after the query the code is

```
if($query) {
while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
echo '<li onClick="window.open(\''.$result->guid.'\');">'.$result->post_title.'</li><br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
        }
```

And it does not fetch anything. I think it's something from the query.
Please help..

Comment: It would be nice to see the table structures.

Comment: Does the query run at all from the mysql CLI?

Answer (score 3):

Change your query to :

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.title LIKE '$query%' 
AND table2.posts LIKE '$query%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Now it's fetching 10 exact same rows from table1.

Answer (score 2):

You can not join conditions like you are trying to, each connective needs to have it's own statement

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.title LIKE '$query%' AND table2.posts LIKE '$query%' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $query->query("SELECT * FROM `table1` AS `t1` JOIN `table2` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`t1id` WHERE `t1`.`title` LIKE '%" . $query . "%' AND `t2`.`posts` LIKE '%" . $query . "%' LIMIT 10;");

if($result ) {
  while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<li onClick="window.open(\'' . $result->guid . '\');">' . $result->post_title . '</li><br>';
  }
}
else
  echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
```

I think it should look something like this.

You should use join and have a field to connect the two tables like this: `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`t1id`

You can use the `table1`, `table2` if you want but still better to use JOIN.

One thing to note when you use LIKE it is better to use percent before and after like this: `LIKE '%" . $query . "%`

Comment: Note: the SQL fragment shown here is only safe if $query has been sanitised against bad or malicious input. Be careful and wherever possible do not use string interpolation (as here) to form SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.title AND table2.posts LIKE '$query%' LIMIT 10
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.title LIKE '$query%' AND table2.posts LIKE '$query%' LIMIT 10
```

or whatever variable you want title to be like

Comment: but I would recomment using join as it is faster if the two tables have title and posts fields in common

Comment: text here if you need help with a join in this case

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.title LIKE '$query%' AND table2.posts LIKE '$query%' LIMIT 10

This query is working just fine. The problem is that it is fetching the right data from table2 but 5-6 to 10 exact same records from table1 which is confusing me.

Comment: please give some examples with data too.

Answer (score 0):

Suhail Patel is correct but not complete, probably.

Depending on your table definitions
    SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.name LIKE x AND table2.name LIKE y;

will return all possible combinations of the fields selected from each table. So if table1 contains the following rows that satisfy LIKE:

```
1
2
3
```

and table2 contains these rows that satisfy LIKE:

```
6
7
8
```

then your result will contain 3x3 = 9 answers:

```
1, 6
1, 7
1, 8
2, 6
2, 7
2, 8
3, 6
3, 7
3, 8
```

To avoid this you must define a relation between the two tables. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.name LIKE x AND table2.name LIKE y AND table1.type = table2.id;
```

This can also be rewritten as a JOIN statement. For more on Joins, this link should help:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html